# Solve inequality after specific variable

Tags: problem-solving

I would appreciate if someone could help me solving the following inequality:

$$ \frac{p^s}{s+1} \ge d$$

We would like to solve the equation for $s$ and can assume that $p,s$ and $d$ are all positive and $p$ and $d$ can be seen as fix numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: Minor pedantry:  this is not an *equation*, since you are not setting things equal to each other.  This is an *inequality.*

Comment: This is not an *equation* it is an inequality and it is not possible to solve in an algebraic way, but only with numerical/graphical methods. To to this we need actual values for the parameters $p,\;d$

Comment: yes this was an error by me, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an example I set $\dfrac{2^s}{s+1}\ge 3$

Then I plotted the function $f(s)=\dfrac{2^s}{s+1}-3$ and found with numerical methods the intersections $s_1\approx -0.81;\;s_2\approx 3.87$

So I can say that the inequality is verified when $f(s)\ge 0$ that is $-1<s\le s_1\lor s\ge s_2$

Hope this is useful

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer! I hoped for an algebraic method, but it seem not to be possible!